# Sobolev spaces involving time

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

In his notes on the Cauchy problem in general relativity, Ringstrom has the following lemma:

**Lemma A.5.**  Let $I$ be an open interval. If $u \in L^\infty(I; H^k(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for some $k \geq 0$, then there is a function $U \in L^2_{\text{loc}}(I \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that for any $\phi \in C_0^\infty(I \times \mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$
\langle \phi, u \rangle = \int_I (\phi(t), u(t))_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\, dt = \int_{I \times \mathbb{R}^n} \phi U\, d(x, t).
$$
Furthemore, for every multi-index $\alpha$, there is a function $U_\alpha \in L^2_{\text{loc}}(I \times \mathbb{R}^n)$, such that for any $\phi \in C_0^\infty (I \times \mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$
\int_{I \times \mathbb{R}^n} \partial^\alpha \phi U\, d(x, t) = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{I \times \mathbb{R}^n} \phi U_\alpha \, d(x, t),
$$
i.e. $U$ is weakly $k$-times differentiable in $x$. What follows is then a somewhat technical (though not super long) proof.

**My question:** (In brief: Why is this needed?) Intuitively, $U$ should just be $u$ itself. My question is, why *isn't* it? Should I view this as a technical lemma that basically lets us work with $U$ instead of $u$, since $u$ is a priori a "stranger" object, in that it actually takes a.e. $t \in I$ and spits out a function $u(t) \in H^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Is the issue here a kind of type-mismatch, in this sense? In that we are just trying to define a more easy-to-work-with object $U$ which is more or less $u$? Or is there something more going on that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I view this as a technical lemma that basically lets us work with $U$ instead of $u$, since $u$ is a priori a "stranger" object, in that it actually takes a.e. $t \in I$ and spits out a function $u(t) \in H^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Probably this. There is danger afoot when you consider $L^\infty$ Bochner spaces: tread carefully. Consider the following example (exercise 1.11 in Robinson, Rodrigo & Sadowski's *The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations*)

> Show that the function defined on $(0,1) \times(0,1)$ by
> $$
> f(x, t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> 0 & x<t \\
> 1 & x \geq t
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> which is clearly an element of $L^{\infty}((0,1) \times(0,1))$, is not an element of $L_{t}^{\infty}\left((0,1) ; L_{x}^{\infty}(0,1)\right) .$ [Hint: define $F:(0,1) \rightarrow L_{x}^{\infty}(0,1)$ by setting
> $F(t)(x)=f(x, t)$, and show that $F^{-1}\left(B_{1 / 2}(F(t))\right)=\{t\}$ for any $t \in(0,1)$
> Hence find an open subset $U$ of $L_{x}^{\infty}(0,1)$ such that $F^{-1}(U)$ is not measurable.] (This example is due to Juan Arias de Reyna.)

Not directly related, but 'switching the argument around' reminded me   also of the following (Paraphrasing of example 1.3.1 in Hamilton's *The Inverse Function Theorem of Nash and Moser*.) Let $C^k_p$ denote the Banach space of $C^k$ $2\pi$-periodic functions, and consider
$$\big( T (t)f\big)(x) = f(x+t)$$
Then

1. $T:\mathbb R\times C^0_p\to C^0_p$ is jointly continuous;
2. $T : \mathbb R \to L(C^0_p, C^0_p)$ is not continuous (wrt operator norm topology);
3. $T:\mathbb R \to L(C^1_p, C^0_p)$ *is* continuous;
4. $T:\mathbb R \to L(C^1_p, C^1_p)$ is *not*.

The lack of continuity in 2 stems from the lack of equicontinuity of the space all functions in $C^0_p$. So obvious sounding things still need to be checked.

Another (even less related) weird thing: if $X$ is infinite dimensional, then simple functions are not dense in $L^\infty(0,T; X)$...if you want to understand Bochner spaces carefully, the first few videos of [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsazbLqk0ktfTAYxZeaWTFD-mwZIpInHC) youtube lecture series by Amenta (which I thoroughly enjoyed) are relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the youtube link, the first video had me hooked!