# Integration along a curve in Banach Spaces, any Measure Theory equivalent?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces

I'm studying Differential Calculus from the A. Avez book, and there's a topic about integration in Banach spaces, the thing is that I noticed that the definition given here is like the Riemann Integral. Is there any equivalent of this integral but from a perspective of measure theory (like the Lebesgue integral in the real case)? If there is, where can I look for more information about it? Thanks in advance and sorry for my broken english.

Comment: Is a Bochner integral the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: :o Omg, after a quick search of that, it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much! Where can I read about it? And what kind of background do I need to learn that?

Comment: Maybe Conca knows

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4123951/80734) answer I wrote and the linked YouTube lecture series is relevant. There were notes but the author’s webpage has disappeared (momentarily?) If I recall correctly it’s also covered in Grandpa Rudin (functional analysis)